# jQuery append method on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to append a div inside order list by clicking a button?
[Onclick this button][1]
This is my button which has id="condition"

```
<button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="condition" value="Add">Condition</button></div>
```

[This should be appended][2]
I'm expecting the o/p to be  as below whenever I click on button

On click 1 the below should be displayed. Append the content which is inside the div

```
sensor <options>
Condition: <option>
Threshold: <input>
```

On clicking button second time the below should be displayed

```
sensor <options>
Condition: <option>
Threshold: <input>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#condition").click(function() {
    $('#shw').append($('.hidden').clone());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden">
  <fieldset>
    <table class='addRuleHolder'>
      <tr>
        <td class="label-col">
          <label>Sensor:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">S1</option>
            <option value="2">S2</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label-col">
          <label>Condition:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">&lt;=</option>
            <option value="2">&gt;=</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label-col">
          <label>Threshold Value:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </fieldset>
</div>


<div style="margin-top: 20px; float:right;padding-right:15px">
      <button  class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="condition" value="Delete">condition</button>
    </div>
<div id="shw"></div>
```

Comment: You need to put it in an <li> for starters

Comment: @mplungjan Tried that way. It didn't work out. I'm only able to display labels, I'm not able to display options

Comment: @mplungjan if I'm writing my code which has to append, .append(code followed by li) it's not loading options

Comment: @mplungjan That display none can be removed and The  <div class="hidden"> should be appended when I click on button. inside ol as list

Comment: @mplungjan please check my required output

Comment: @mplungjan The div with hidden class should be shown inside ol .

Comment: Ahh. `$("ol").append($(".hidden").clone());`

Comment: @mplungjanThanks worked out. my bad . Thank you so much

Comment: @mplungjan Small issue. on clicking second time it's showing me three times. on clicking 3rd time its showing 7 times. can you help me the snippet to be working .Thanks  :)

Comment: @mplungjan did'nt work out :( Any suggestion

Comment: @mplungjan now please check snippet and click on button. on click 2nd time i need the div only one time to append . like 5 click total should be only 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the class hidden from the clones.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#condition").click(function() {
    $('#shw').append($('.hidden').clone().removeClass("hidden"));
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden">
  <fieldset>
    <table class='addRuleHolder'>
      <tr>
        <td class="label-col">
          <label>Sensor:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">S1</option>
            <option value="2">S2</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label-col">
          <label>Condition:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">&lt;=</option>
            <option value="2">&gt;=</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label-col">
          <label>Threshold Value:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </fieldset>
</div>


<div style="margin-top: 20px; float:right;padding-right:15px">
  <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="condition" value="Add">condition</button>
</div>
<br style="clear:both"/>
<div id="shw"></div>
```

Comment: yeah definitely i will look into it

Comment: Sir, I have more doubt. As I'm trying to send the complete data inside a form <form></form>.But the data of the div which is appended is being sent as undefined. Can you please explain me. Your leads will be very helpful for me. Thankyou

Comment: Are you appending the div to the form or to a div outside the form? Please ask a new question if it is not obvious

Comment: sir please check this out, posted a question with a snippet
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988790/im-not-able-to-send-the-complete-form-data-using-ng-submit-appended-div-data-i

Comment: I'm appending the div inside the form
 <form><table>condition(data is being sent to backend) </table><div class=""hidden> append content(sending as undefined)</div> <button type="submit"></button></form>