# I'm not able to send the complete form data using ng-submit. Appended div data is being sent as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-scope

I'm not able to send the complete form data using ng-submit.I'm able to send the data containing even name, event status, trigger event and relay state.
The data of the appended div is being sent as undefined.Thankyou

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);
app.controller("ruleCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#condition").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery('#shw').append(jQuery('.hiddenRule').clone().removeClass("hiddenRule"));
    });
  });
  jQuery('#shw').on('click', '#delete', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).parent().remove();
  });
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#condition").click(function() {
      jQuery('#add').show();
    });
  });
  $scope.addRule = function() { //to add
    var dataObj = {
      configuration: {
        rule: {
          name: $scope.eventname,
          status: $scope.eventstatus,
          triggerOn: $scope.triggerevent,
          onSuccess: $scope.relaystate,
          conditions: [{
              fact: $scope.sensor,
              operator: $scope.condition,
              value: $scope.thresholdvalue,
            }
            /*{ fact: "t1",
              operator: "greaterThan",
              value: 40
              },
              {
              fact: "h1",
              operator: "lessThanInclusive",
              value: 122
              } */
          ]
        }
      }
    };
    console.log(dataObj);
    $http.post('/v1/relay/configuration/add', dataObj)
      .then(function(result) {},
        function(data, status) {});
  };
}])
```

```css
.hiddenRule {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="ruleCtrl">

    <form ng-submit="addRule()">
      <fieldset>
        <table class='addRuleHolder'>
          <tr>
            <td class="label-col">
              <label>Event Name:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" ng-model="eventname">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="label-col">
              <label>Event status:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select ng-model="eventstatus">
                <option value="enabled">Enabled</option>
                <option value="disabled">Disabled</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="label-col">
              <label>Trigger Event:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select ng-model="triggerevent">
                <option value="all">All Conditions</option>
                <option value="any">Any Conditions</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="label-col">
              <label>Relay State:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select ng-model="relaystate">
                <option value="1">On</option>
                <option value="0">Off</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="margin-top: 20px; float:right;padding-right:15px">
          <button id="condition">Condition</button>
        </div>
      </fieldset>

      <div class="hiddenRule">
        <fieldset>
          <table class='addRuleHolder'>
            <tr>
              <td class="label-col">
                <label>Sensor:</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select ng-model="sensor">
                  <option value="s1">S1</option>
                  <option value="s2">S2</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="label-col">
                <label>Condition:</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select ng-model="condition">
                  <option value="lessThan">&lt;</option>
                  <option value="lessThanInclusive">&lt;=</option>
                  <option value="greaterThan">&gt;</option>
                  <option value="greaterThanInclusive">&gt;=</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="label-col">
                <label>Threshold Value:</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="thresholdvalue">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <button style="margin-top: 20px; float:right;padding-right:15px" id="delete">delete</button>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <br style="clear:both" />
      <div id="shw"></div>
      <button style="margin-top: 20px; float:right;padding-right:15px;margin-right: 10px; display:none" type="submit" value="Add" id="add">Add Schedule</button>

    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone help me out how to submit the complete data? Your leads would be very helpful for me.Sorry for my bad English and it might be a silly mistake, please correct me as I'm new to angularjs.

[image: Condition is main div and The button with delete is appeded div. On click condition, div will be appended]

Comment: @mplungjan Sir, even pure JavaScript or jQuery would help me out. I just need to send complete data Including the data of appended div

Comment: I have no idea how you submit.

Comment: @mplungjan sir, I want to send all the data to the backend. please have a look at above. I just uploaded the image of the required output which I'm looking for

Comment: But your question sounds like you can send the form but when it arrives, any dynamic content is missing. I do not know how angular submits a form but so far I do not see a serialize or similar at submit time

Comment: @mplungjan Sir, how can we send this using javascript or jQuery?Like you explained to me how does append works and the hidden class should be removed to display one time on each click. Can you please update that snippet for my better understanding? It will be useful for many of beginners like me. I didn't find any similar example

Comment: `$("form").on("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $.post("someserverprocess",$(this).serialize(),function(response) { console.log(response) });`

Comment: @mplungjan Tq sir, will try and get back to you :)

Comment: @mplungjan please check this and make any necessary changes
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49009381/how-to-send-form-data-using-jquery-in-which-one-div-is-being-appended-on-click