# send Form data using jQuery which has appended div inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm not able to send the complete form data using form.I'm able to send the stored data containing even name, event status, trigger event and relay state. The data of the appended div is being sent as the value which is stored in its previous values.

```js
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#condition").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#shw').append($('.hiddenRule').clone().removeClass("hiddenRule"));
                });
            });
            $('#shw').on('click', '#delete', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#condition").click(function () {
                    $('#add').show();
                });
            });
            /*data format*/
            var obj= {
                configuration: {
                    rule: {
                        name: $("#eventname").val(),
                        status: $("#eventstatus").val(),
                        triggerOn: $("#triggerevent").val(),
                        onSuccess: $("#relaystate").val(),
                        conditions: [
                            {
                                fact: $("#sensor").val(),
                                operator: $("#condition").val(),
                                value: $("#thresholdvalue").val(),
                                }
                            ]
                    }
                }
            };
            $("form").click("submit",obj,  function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.post('url',$(this).serialize(), function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                         })
                    })
```

```css
.hiddenRule{
 display:none;
 }
```

```html
<html>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
    <body>

    <div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="ruleCtrl">
     
    <form>
            <fieldset>
                <table class='addRuleHolder'>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label-col">
                            <label>Event Name:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="eventname">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label-col">
                            <label>Event status:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="eventstatus">
                                <option value="enabled">Enabled</option>
                                <option value="disabled">Disabled</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label-col">
                            <label>Trigger Event:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="triggerevent">
                                <option value="all">All Conditions</option>
                                <option value="any">Any Conditions</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label-col">
                            <label>Relay State:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="relaystate">
                                <option value="1">On</option>
                                <option value="0">Off</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div style="margin-top: 20px; float:right;padding-right:15px">
                    <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="condition">Condition</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <div class="hiddenRule">
                <fieldset>
                    <table class='addRuleHolder'>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label-col">
                                <label>Sensor:</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="sensor">
                                    <option value="s1">S1</option>
                                    <option value="s2">S2</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label-col">
                                <label>Condition:</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="condition">
                                    <option value="lessThan">&lt;</option>
                                    <option value="lessThanInclusive">&lt;=</option>
                                    <option value="greaterThan">&gt;</option>
                                    <option value="greaterThanInclusive">&gt;=</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label-col">
                                <label>Threshold Value:</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="thresholdvalue">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <button style="margin-top: 20px; float:right;padding-right:15px" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="delete">delete</button>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <br style="clear:both" />
            <div id="shw"></div>
            <button style="margin-top: 20px; float:right;padding-right:15px;margin-right: 10px; display:none" type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" value="Add" id="add">Add Schedule</button>
        
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

even if I append two times, still the data is only being sent for the first one with the previous values(i'm not able to send even empty or stored data for the div which is being appended the second time), but not the selected values.
Can anyone help me out how to submit the complete data? Your leads would be very helpful for me.Thankyou

[image: This is the o/p i'm looking for]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways you can clean this up. I have no way to test the POST functionality. I would advise the following:

```js
$(function() {
  function collectData($f) {
    var obj = {
      configuration: {
        rule: {
          name: $f.find(".name").val(),
          status: $f.find(".status option:selected").val(),
          triggerOn: $f.find(".trigger option:selected").val(),
          onSuccess: $f.find(".state option:selected").val(),
          conditions: []
        }
      }
    };
    if ($f.find(".conditionHolder").length) {
      $f.find(".conditionHolder").each(function(index, elem) {
        var $item = $(elem);
        obj.configuration.rule.conditions.push({
          fact: $item.find(".sensor option:selected").val(),
          operator: $item.find(".condition option:selected").val(),
          value: parseInt($item.find(".threshold").val()),
        });
      });
    }
    console.log(obj);
    return obj;
  }

  function makeCondition() {
    var $c = $(".hiddenRule").clone();
    var c = $("form .conditionHolder").length + 1;
    $c.removeClass("hiddenRule");
    $c.find(".delete").before("Condition " + c + " ");
    $("#shw").append($c);
  }

  $("#condition").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    makeCondition();
  });

  $('#shw').on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
  });

  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myData = collectData($(this));
    /*
    $.post('url', myData, function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
    */
    console.log("My Data:", myData);
  });
});
```

```css
.hiddenRule {
  display: none;
}

.conditionHolder {
  border: 0;
  border-top: 2px groove #f1f0ef;
  border-bottom: 2px groove #f1f0ef;
  margin-left: -11px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.conditionHolder legend {
  background: #fff;
}

.conditionHolder .delete {
  background: #f1f0ef;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 13.33px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="ruleCtrl">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <table class="addRuleHolder">
        <tr>
          <td class="label-col">
            <label>Event Name:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="event name">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="label-col">
            <label>Event status:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select class="event status">
              <option value="enabled">Enabled</option>
              <option value="disabled">Disabled</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="label-col">
            <label>Trigger Event:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select class="event trigger">
              <option value="all">
                All Conditions
              </option>
              <option value="any">
                Any Conditions
              </option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="label-col">
            <label>Relay State:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select class="event relay state">
              <option value="1">On</option>
              <option value="0">Off</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div id="shw"></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 20px; float:right;padding-right:15px">
        <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="condition">Condition</button>
      </div>

    </fieldset>
    <button style="margin-top: 20px; float:right;padding-right:15px;margin-right: 10px;" type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" value="Add" id="add">Add Schedule</button>
    <br style="clear:both" />
  </form>
</div>
<!-- Rule Template -->
<div class="hiddenRule">
  <fieldset class='conditionHolder'>
    <legend><button class="delete" title="Delete Condition">X</button></legend>
    <table class="addRuleHolder">
      <tr>
        <td class="label-col">
          <label>Sensor:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="event sensor">
                <option value="s1">S1</option>
                <option value="s2">S2</option>
              </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label-col">
          <label>Condition:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="event condition">
                <option value="lessThan">&lt;</option>
                <option value="lessThanInclusive">&lt;=</option>
                <option value="greaterThan">&gt;</option>
                <option value="greaterThanInclusive">&gt;=</option>
              </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label-col">
          <label>Threshold Value:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="event threshold">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Your code was assigning two click events to `#condition` and was generating console errors. Hope this helps.

**Update**

Moved away from `id` to `class` for a number of the elements. Seek for `conditions` and append them to the data object within an array for each condition.

**Sample Results**

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "rule": {
      "name": "Shutdown",
      "status": "enabled",
      "triggerOn": "all",
      "onSuccess": "1",
      "conditions": [
        {
          "fact": "s1",
          "operator": "lessThan",
          "value": 5
        },
        {
          "fact": "s2",
          "operator": "greaterThan",
          "value": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Twisty thanks for responding. I'm looking for the output which I have posted above. I'm not able to send any data of appended div. That's what my problem is

Comment: Oops sorry for editing your code instead of mine, my bad, it was done by mistake, I'm unable to undo.Sorry Twisty

Comment: @Sai no problem. I rejected the edit. Your reply: *This is what i'm looking for. Please check the image. The output* https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtKN0.png

Comment: Thanks, Twisty, Can you please help me to achieve the output which I'm looking for. Trying for two days, I'm unable to solve it  :(

Comment: @Sai yes. Based on your image, the use of `id` attribute in your cloned elements is cuasing a problem. Each ID should be unique in HTML. Since multiple fields have the same ID, jQuery is unable to select one. Will update my answer with a better example.

Comment: Twisty that would be very helpful for me to understand better :) Thankyou.

Note: The number of the array in condition depends on the number of times we append the div. If I append two times and submit the form The data of rule and the data of two appended div's should also be sent

Comment: Twisty you are awesome.Thank you so much